# How to install EasyBCD?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uninstall, easybcd

I want to delete ubuntu 11.10 from dual boot system(windows 7 + ubuntu 11.10). I currently have ubuntu as main OS but I don't want to continue with it further.I don't have CD for win 7 so I am trying other sources. 
I have downloaded EasyBCD on another system and pasted it on ubuntu. It is .exe file and is not running on ubuntu. I am not aware of any commands regarding installation and further process. :(

So,pls suggest what to do next,I would be very thankful. :)

Comment: " I have downloaded EasyBCD on another system and pasted it on ubuntu. It is .exe file and is not running on ubuntu." EasyBCD is a Windows program ans needs to be in Windows not Ubuntu.

Comment: so what can be done to remove ubuntu then..?

Comment: @Kriti - I've dropped an answer for you - basically any other non ubuntu route is off-topic for this site.  Our friends in SuperUser StackExchange may be able to help you with a Windows friendly route.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions but the problem is I am unable to run Windows 7 and I can only run ubuntu on my laptop so, I have to uninstall it using ubuntu itself. any suggestions regarding this.

Comment: If you cannot run windows 7 - what is the problem here? Removing ubuntu will not fix windows 7 from not working.  If you do not have a licensed copy of windows then we cannot help you with installing windows.

Answer (score 3):

EasyBCD is a windows program.

According to the author (see comments):

> Author of EasyBCD here. You can't run it in Wine, as it has many, many dependencies on the kernel and also uses .NET. – Mahmoud Al-Qudsi

This is confirmed by looking at [winehq](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10411) - both results are given as "garbage" - which basically means those versions tested do not work.

Thus, you will need to find another route - I would strongly advise finding a licensed Windows 7 CD and then fixing your MBR through this recovery CD as per this Q&A

[How to completely wipe Ubuntu 11.10 from HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90947/how-to-completely-wipe-ubuntu-11-10-from-hdd)

Comment: could you pls tell me doing it without win 7 CD...would b gr8 help.

Comment: I'm not aware of any **recommended** Ubuntu method to fix a windows MBR.  Whilst it may be theoretically possible I would strongly advise against any **non-Microsoft recommended** method because you could be left with a non-booting system - besides your laptop should have come with a recovery partition allowing you to restore your Windows 7 system.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestions but the problem is I am unable to run Windows 7 and I can only run ubuntu on my laptop so, I have to uninstall it using ubuntu itself.
any suggestions regarding this.?

Comment: Author of EasyBCD here. You can't run it in Wine, as it has many, many dependencies on the kernel and also uses .NET.

Answer (score 1):

First of all EASY BCD is a Windows application (.exe file) so installing it in Ubuntu is not a good idea.

Deleting the Ubuntu partition will render Windows 7 unbootable as GRUB has overridden Windows Bootloader in the master Bootloader.

Best option for you is to install EASY BCD (application you just downloaded) in your Windows 7 partition to recover Windows Bootloader.

Here is how: 
1. Launch the EASY BCD.

1. Select BCD DEPLOYMENT option and choose 'Install the Windows Vista/7 Bootloader to the MBR' option available in this option
2. Select 'Write MBR' and finish the process with a reboot.
3. You can now format the Ubuntu partition in Windows 7 using the Disk Management tool

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion but the problem is Windows 7 isn't running and I can only run ubuntu on my laptop so, I have to uninstall it using ubuntu itself.  Moreover, I am also not able to connect to wireless networks which was possible before installing ubuntu.

Comment: @Mysterio - whilst we may sympathise with the OP - please do not suggest to "google" for pirated material.

Comment: Didn't know the recovery disc iso was for sale now. They use to offer it for free. That's how I got mine 2 years ago. My bad then

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recovery media from windows 7 itself. It will help if you got into any more trouble. Just search for `Create a System Repair Disc` in start menu and burn it to a blnk cd/dvd. The you can boot from it and do a start up repair.

Comment: That link contains links to pirated material - please **do not post such links** in the future on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't check properly, thought that discs can be used for free.